# my custom delegate doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

i'm using delegation between two classes in order to be notified in case there's any update or an object needs to be added. the first class is a subclass of UITableViewController and the second is a subclass of UIViewController. the first class has a plus (addButton) to add objects to it's table view. the second class is the view that the first navigates to when the add button is pressed. So in the view controller class i added a protocol in the .h file:

```
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) addViewControllerDelegate:(ViewController *)controller didUpdateEvent:(Event *) event;

@end
```

and i added a delegate @propety:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SSAddViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

in the .m file added the following in the IBAction method that gets triggered when the save button pressed:

```
[self.delegate addViewControllerDelegate:self didUpdateEvent: event];
```

now going back to the table view controller class, in the .h file i added  and in the .m file i added the following method:

```
- (void) addViewControllerDelegate:(ViewController *)controller didUpdatEvent:(Event *)event{
    [self saveNewEntry:event];
    NSLog(@"DELEGATE");
}
```

PROBLEM: it's not working. although i guess i made everything that should be done.

Notes: i altered the names of classes here so no i didn't have my class called ViewController. 
saveNewEntry is used to add the event object to my array and the nslog is there so that to known if it did enter the method.

//---------------------------------- more actual code ------------------------------
Second class (view controller) .h and .m respectively

```
@class Course;
@class SSAddViewController;

@protocol SSAddViewControllerDelegate;

@interface SSAddViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SSAddViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol SSAddViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) addViewControllerDelegate:(SSAddViewController *)controller didUpdateCourse:(Course *) course;

@end
@class Course;
@class SSAddViewController;

@protocol SSAddViewControllerDelegate;

@interface SSAddViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SSAddViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol SSAddViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) addViewControllerDelegate:(SSAddViewController *)controller didUpdateCourse:(Course *) course;

@end

- (void) saveNewEntry
{
    SSAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    Course *course = (Course *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Course" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSLog(@"YES");
    [course setCourseName:self.nameTextField.text];
    [course setCourseCredits:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.creditstextField.text intValue]]];
    [course setCourseChapters:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.chaptersTextField.text intValue]]];

    if (hasChanges) {
        [self.delegate addViewControllerDelegate:self didUpdateCourse:course];
    }
}
```

first class (table view ) .h and .m respectively :

```
@interface SSCoursesViewController : UITableViewController <SSAddViewControllerDelegate>




- (void) addViewControllerDelegate:(SSAddViewController *)controller didUpdateCourse:(Course *)course{
    [self saveNewEntry:course];
    NSLog(@"DELEGATE");
}
```

Comment: do you ever set the delegate?

Comment: you mean the one i added ? the @property delegate ?

Comment: yes, somewhere in your code you need to set that to something, otherwise, nothing will ever happen

Comment: i did type [self.delegate addViewController:self didUpdateEvent:event] is that what you mean by setting it ? actually i don't even know to set delegate to anything other than this.

Comment: btw i checked the Utility template and my code is similar to it. the only time delegate is used is the same as my case (as the one i posted in the previous comment)

Comment: no, somewhere you need to set `delegate = something`. This can be in either location. It would be easier to give you an explicit answer if you put more of your code in the question (we don't even know the name of your two classes, although one appears to be ViewController).

Comment: see answer posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your SSAddViewController created? Do you use a segue as part of your storyboard or are you creating it directly?

if you are using a segue, you need to implement prepareForSeque in your SSCoursesViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SSAddViewController *ssavc = (SSAddViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

    ssavc.delegate = self;

}
```

if you are creating the SSAddViewController directly, you can set it directly.

I'm not sitting at my Mac right now, but the code above is approximately correct.

Comment: yes the SSAddViewController is a view controller which is created by a modal segue. i'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually set in your code `SSAddViewControllerDelegate = self;`?

Comment: mm..no what delegate you mean > the one i typed as an id ?

Comment: @user1938695 What he means is did you set the view controller's `delegate` property to some value?

Comment: oh no i didn't. if i should were do i need to do that? in it's setter? and to what value ?